# how to find the highest most repeated number in an integer

Tags: java

for example if
int number = 30530;

it has to return 3`

this is what I tried but it's over my mind, I don't know where I lost it and I also would appreciate it if there is any other way to do it without converting it to String

```
public static int maharishi(int functionNum){
    String num = Integer.toString(functionNum);
  int length = num.length();
  int count = 0;
  int tempCount =  0;
  int charLetter = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i < length; i++ ){
        for(int j = 1; j < length; j++){
            if(i==1 && j!=1 ){
                if(num.charAt(i) == num.charAt(j)){
                    tempCount++;
                    if(tempCount > count){
                        count = tempCount;
                        charLetter = i;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    char highestChar = num.charAt(charLetter);
    int change = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(highestChar));
    return change;

}
```

Comment: I am surprised by the nested loops. Why not just count the 0s, 1s, 2s, .... 9s?

Comment: how,  enlighten me

Comment: Are you aware of arrays? You can have one with 10 entries and use each digit as index to increment the corresponding entry.  .... Hmmm, and then loop over the array to find the highest count.... Maybe your approach is not that bad after all. ;-)

Comment: To get the low order digit use ``n % 10``. Then use ``n = n/10`` to shift the number one digit right.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Map<Character, Integer>`:

```java
public static int maharishiMaheshYogi(int functionNum){
    // Convert the number to a string 
    String num = Integer.toString(functionNum);
  
    // Create a Map where you will store each character count
    final Map<Character, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();

    // Iterate over each character of this string
    final int length = num.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        final char c = num.charAt(i);
        
        // Increment the value of its respective character in the map
        final int currentCount = counts.getOrDefault(c, 0);
        counts.put(c, currentCount + 1);
    }
    
    // Return the key with the maximum value in the map
    Map.Entry<Character, Integer> maxEntry = null;
    for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
        if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue()) {
            maxEntry = entry;
        }
    }
    return Integer.parseInt(maxEntry.getKey().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your middle `if` condition make all fails, you count only when `i` is 0, so you don't look to other values,
- also make the comparison `if` after the inner loop, don't need to check for every value
- the `inner` loop should start at `i+1` to read only next chars
- `tempCount` should be re-initialized at `0` at every round of outer loop

```
public static int maharishi(int functionNum) {
    String num = Integer.toString(functionNum);
    int length = num.length();
    int count = 0, bestPosition = 0, tempCount;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char c = num.charAt(i);
        tempCount = 0;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (c == num.charAt(j)) {
                tempCount++;
            }
        }

        if (tempCount > count) {
            count = tempCount;
            bestPosition = i;
        }
    }

    char highestChar = num.charAt(bestPosition);
    return Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(highestChar));
}

// testing
System.out.println(maharishi(1234));  // 1
System.out.println(maharishi(12344)); // 4
System.out.println(maharishi(12343)); // 3
System.out.println(maharishi(12342)); // 2
```

---

For `Stream` lovers

```
public static int maharishi(int functionNum) {
    String l = Arrays.stream(Integer.toString(functionNum).split(""))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
            .orElseThrow()
            .getKey();
    return Integer.parseInt(l);
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works , i am trying to understand  all my mistakes, is there a way to do it without converting it to string ?

Comment: @AbelKibebe Not really, that is a nice way to access the different elements easily ;)

Comment: Nice ... Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to convert to string, the easiest way would be to use a "helper array" to hold the count for every possible digit from 0 to 9.

```
public static int maharishi(int functionNum) {
    int [] counts = new int[10];

    //count all the digits in the number:
    while (functionNum > 0) {
        counts[functionNum % 10] += 1;
        functionNum /= 10;
    }

    int record = -1;
    int mostRepeated = -1;

    //find higest most repeated digit
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++) {
        if (counts[i] >= record) {
            record = counts[i]; //how many times this digit is in the number
            mostRepeated = i; //what digit it is
    }

    return mostRepeated;
}
```

What it does is:

1. Count each digit in the number. Separates digits by division an modulus (remainder).
   To separate a digit from a number without converting to string, just get a remainder of division by 10.
2. Run over the counts from 0 to 9, and store which count is biggest. Return the digit (index) that count belongs to, that is your answer.

You can do this without the array, but you would need more loops.
The principle of separating digits by modulus and division remains the same.